# How to get support of generators in typescript without setting target to ES6?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Got a situation here.
I use nodejs with `--harmony` flag to get support of generators.
Next i'm trying to switch my project to TypeScript and get a problem: in `"target":"ES6"` mode it transpiles `import` commands as is (instead of `require`).

And node with `--harmony` flag doesn't support that:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Transpiling option `"module":"commonjs` isn't allowed with `"target":"ES6"`.

Have anyone solved this problem without using any external require/import utilities?

Comment: Another side of the problem is that TypeScript transpiles `var fs = require('fs');` into `import * as fs from 'fs';` on it's own. So, no way to avoid `import` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These settings have worked for me:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
  }
}
```

- ES6 support for generators
- No `import` stuff transpiling due to
  `"moduleResolution": "classic"`

And so the problem's gone!

Comment: We still couldn't achieve this using solely ts, I guess we need separate transpiler like babel to convert final es6 file to es5

Comment: OP: "...without setting target to ES6?" also OP: `"target":"ES6"`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [TypeScript roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) (Version 1.7) one of the current issues is ["Support --module with --target es6"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4806).

I'm afraid your are going to need a temporal solution until TypeScript  1.7 is released. Maybe [Polyfill for the ES6 Module Loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader) or [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get all i want is a build stack:

1. Transpile TS to ES6
2. Transpile es6-js to es5-js with Babel